# Word for a person who avoids a few topics

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word to describe a person who does not discuss a few topics. He/She **does not sidestep** the topic, he/she frankly tells that they do not want to discuss that particular topic.

e.g. If you ask person X about topics like world news, today's weather, past relationships, etc he/she freely discusses them. But if you ask that person about his/her food preferences, he/she responds saying that, "I do not want to talk about food preferences ever again."

Comment: *who does not discuss few topics* - so he/she discusses *many* topics?

Comment: I thought "discuss few topics" was intended to mean "discuss a few topics," i.e., a few topics are refused.  [Other topics are freely discussed.]  The question needs a sample sentence.

Comment: A few topics are "off-limits."

Comment: particular in what they discuss?  Reticent when it come to politics?

Comment: Maybe they just think you are being intrusive in their personal affairs?

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to convey is that a person does not answer certain questions but instead talks about other things to distract you and waste time maybe you could use 'Evasive' or 'Beating around the bush'.

> Evasive- tending to avoid commitment or self-revelation, especially by responding only indirectly.

An example could be

> He/ She was being evasive when asked about the project deadlines.

Or

> Beating around the bush - Approach indirectly, in a roundabout way, or too cautiously.

An example could be

> Stop beating around the bush and give me the files that I asked for.

If the intention is to convey that a person is directly declining to answer some questions they could be acting 'defensive'or just 'frank'

Comment: are you sure about *frank*?

Comment: Yes if the intention is to convey that the person does not talk about anything else to distract and outright declines to answer some questions. An example of this could be your manager refusing to talk about oncoming promotions because they prefer to not spin stories and refuse directly to discourage any other questions on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

uncooperative? secretive? strong minded? obstructive?

Comment: These are good suggestions, but please provide definitions for each of them to demonstrate why they work for the OP's request.